# Hibernate Tools

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql

I am new in the hibernate world. My project task is to represent xml result from the SQL database. To do so, first step, I am trying to generate POJOs and mapping xml from my db by using hibernate tools auto generating feature. When, i am trying to generate a simple database (2/3 tables) its working fine.

But while i trying to convert my real database, which has 28 tables within different table relationships. Then i am facing the below problem. Not able to connect the database tables. Hibernate tools configuration showing this terrible message.(**Foreign key name (fk_p_einheit) mapped to different tables! previous: org.hibernate.mapping.Table(public.einheit_quelle) current:org.hibernate.mapping.Table(public.spalten**)

I checked google to get the solution but not get any proper solution related to eclipse IDE. Just got one BUG report from NetBeans site(https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205863).

My setup configuration is:eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64, postgres (sql 9.1-901.jdbc4) and hibernate core (4.3.5.Final) with maven project and hibernate tools.

Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need an object model that maps all of those 28 tables and relationships.  Do you have one?  If not, why are you using Hibernate?

You can ask Hibernate to generate an object model for you from the schema.  Try it.

Why are you using all these unknown technologies (Hibernate, Eclipse, etc.) to do something simple?

If you're thinking in terms of tables and columns, and not objects, I'd say you'd be better off writing JDBC and straight SQL.  ORM tools aren't for you.